# Save and Close Icon

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, icon, interface-design, user-experience

I'm building an interface for an admin page. The admin clicks a button to choose an icon to save and close the data table instead of autosave.

I have always been stumped as to which icon is best suited for use on the "Save & Close" button.

Don't want to use the usual floppy disk(save) and cross(close). Wondering is there a better idea to design a icon.

Comment: Why not use the disk icon? It's already widely known and users won't be confused.

Comment: Widely used everywhere but need something more creative.

Comment: It is funny though, how most people today have never seen a floppy disk in real life, possibly some don't even know what a floppy disk is, but the icon is still being used alot.

Comment: But why do you need something more creative? Just for the sake of creativity? That's not what UI/UX is about.

Comment: I completely understand but, when higher management expect it. I've no answer about creativity in it :(

Answer (score 3):

Well I'm sure this is not as 'creative' as your management probably expects you to go into [Einstein-mode](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132760) and invent what nobody else did, but.. moving away from floppies and drives and all that explicit symbolism, you can just type the name of the action and use a good old checkmark.

You're done working, so you 'Save and Close', right?

[image]